# Linux + convert RAID0 to RAID1 on Blade Server HS21

Tags: raid-1

I have HS21 blade server 
My blade server configured as RAID0 – one disk ( disk with red-hat Linux OS )
My target is to configure the blade server to RAID1 – mirror with 2 disks ( I need to add second disk)

My question – how to configure the blade server to RAID1, without making any change on my disk, someone have procedure or tool that can do this?

Diana